# How to deploy the result of a goal izpack:izpack

Tags: maven, deployment, izpack

I'm trying to deploy thanks to maven, the result of the izpack packaging.

I have two projects.
The parent, that gathers plugins configuration :

- org.codehaus.izpack:izpack-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-5

  installerFile = ${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}

  izpackBasedir = ${basedir}/target/izpack
- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin

  file = ${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}

And I have a project another project, which use the project above as a parent.
This project's pom make the izpack:izpack goal "single" during the package phase.

Deploy plugin fails because the ${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName} is not found.

When I look into the target dir, the ${project.build.finalName}.jar file is there.
When I look into my local repository, into the [groupId dir]/[artefactId dir]/[version dir], the izpack packaged jar file id there and works perfectly. So I think the install phase works correctly.

The only issue is during the deploy phase.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = ${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}
```

should probably point to a file and which it does not. Append `.jar` and it will find the file.

```
file = ${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.jar
```

Comment: I also tried with ".jar" and it doesn't work. I don't understand why the phase "install" seems to work, and not the "deploy".

Comment: @WilhelmPeraud What goal are you using for the `maven-deploy-plugin`? And also, could you display your project layout better in the question?